# Custom page under custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have several custom post types, but for this question I will use just two, **houses and condominiums**.

A condominium has a lot of houses.

I already created these two custom post types and it's working. When I access archive-houses (/houses), it brings all the houses. If I access archive-condominiums (condominiums), it brings all of it as well.

If I access single-condominiums (/condominiums/some-cond) and single-houses (/houses/some-house/), it shows the information for each item selected. Working as well!

Now, I would like to bring all the houses by condominiums, when I access something like this:

**/condominiums/{condominium}/{houses}**

How to create this page with this hierarchy inside this custom post type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

while registering post type for condominiums you might have used an array of arguments, on that add with_front argument with the desired url and than save permalinks,

check here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

'with_front' => bool Should the permalink structure be prepended with the front base. (example: if your permalink structure is /blog/, then your links will be: false->/news/, true->/blog/news/). Defaults to true

Comment: It's not that what I need. I have condominiums as post types and also houses. If I access /condominiums and /condominiums/slug-cond, I can see working, but how to create a custom page inside /condominiums/slug-cond/houses to list the houses for this condominium?

Comment: i am not sure if you already know about taxonomy, here seems you want condominiums as taxonomy (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) so you can categorize houses under condominiums. so houses as posttype and condominiums as taxonomy.            Did i misunderstood?

Comment: Maybe you're right. My problem to understand is, condominium will have its own information like description, image gallery and more. That's why I put as a custom post type. It will have a page for it as well. I'm going to read more about taxonomy and see if it can fit in this scenario.

Comment: yes more easier is to make taxonomy and use custom fields for taxonomy to make image gallery and more etc, that is one way. You can use advance custom field plugin for easier way to add custom field on taxonomy.                    you can also use post type, but than you will have to define a relation between them, and save it as custom field and than rewrite rules wil also have to be writtem all these things are taken care if you use taxonomy,